# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_io'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create my own object detection model with TensorFlow 1 in the Anaconda environment. I wanted to use TensorFlow 1.15 and I followed this tutorial
https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi

Cuz I'm new to this I followed tutorials on how to set up TensorFlow when I reach the step on setting up TensorFlow, I used the command
**pip install .**
to install TensorFlow using the setup.py in the research directory

After the installation, I used the command to test the TensorFlow setup to verify it works:

**python builders\model_builder_tf1_test.py**

However, I face the below error:

```
**(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python builders\model_builder_tf1_test.py
2021-11-15 15:00:30.638411: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-11-15 15:00:30.638523: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "builders\model_builder_tf1_test.py", line 21, in
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 37, in
from object_detection.meta_architectures import deepmac_meta_arch
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\meta_architectures\deepmac_meta_arch.py", line 28, in
import tensorflow_io as tfio # pylint:disable=g-import-not-at-top
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_io'**
```

Does anyone know why does this happens, Is it because I didn't install the Tensorflow correctly? Do I just do python install for the missing module?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Try to install the library using pip:

```
pip install tensorflow-io
```

Comment: pip install tensorflow-io

Comment: This worked for me: pip install tensorflow_io

Answer (score 7):

Use `pip install tensorflow_io`
NOT `tensorflow-io`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).