# Cannot import tensorflow_io

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting ModuleNotFoundError when I try to import tensorflow_io.

I tried to fix the error as described in [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_io'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69970867/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-io) but it didn't work with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following and I was able to have the module imported in my machine,

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow_io
```

then in a file.py you can import them

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
```

I figure you need the tensorflow module installed if you want to use the tensorflow_io.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I created a new environment and installed tensorflow and tensorflow_io and this worked for me